# Branch mainnet-pack-validator gives error "tezos-node: Error: Not_found"

Tags: tezos-client

`./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732
Aug 29 13:13:38 - node.main: Starting the Tezos node...
Aug 29 13:13:38 - node.main: No local peer discovery.
Aug 29 13:13:38 - node.main: Peer's global id: idts1aYiNgUVV3dehNx6qRmd4UzTgA
Aug 29 13:13:38 - main: shell-node initialization: bootstrapping
Aug 29 13:13:38 - main: shell-node initialization: p2p_maintain_started
Aug 29 13:13:38 - shell.validation_process.fork: Initialized
Aug 29 13:13:38 - shell.validation_process.fork: Block validation started on pid 13389
Aug 29 13:13:39 - main: validator-block : Worker started(2019-08-29T13:13:39-00:00)
Aug 29 13:13:39 - node.validator: activate chain NetXdQprcVkpaWU
Aug 29 13:13:39 - p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)
Aug 29 13:13:39 - main: validator-chain_1 : Worker started for NetXdQprcVkpa(2019-08-29T13:13:39-00:00)
tezos-node: Error:
              Not_found`

Comment: Can you try to start from an empty context? I was able to reproduce this bug by starting from a LMDB context (i.e. from branch mainnet), and then switching to branch mainnet-pack-validator, which uses another storage format and thus cannot read LMDP contexts. Instead of producing a nice error message it produces "Not_found" and this is probably what you are encountering.

Comment: @romain I was already using a context from branch mainnet-pack-validator. I updated to the latest commit (_fix lib_delegate which was based on another version of Context_) and then the error happened. Should I clear and restart from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the format of the "pack" backend (in experimental branch `mainnet-pack-validator`) recently changed. It is possible that by updating to the latest version of this branch, you went from the old format to the new format. In that case you probably need to start from the beginning, unfortunately.